# Configuring navigations through owned types in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, owned-types

### Ask a question

My goal is to create a value object as an owned type, and to configure the relationship of the owner to another table through this valueobject.

So in my case I have a Person, and a Person has a PhoneNumber. A PhoneNumber is a string column and an int column, where the int column is a foreign key to a Country table.

I want my Person to look like this

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And my Phone class is like this:

```cs
public class PhoneNumber : ValueObject
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Country is just any table.

```cs
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured Person like this:

```cs
   builder.OwnsOne(o => o.Phone, options =>
        {
            options.Property(p => p.Number).HasColumnName($"PhoneNumber");
            options.HasOne(x => x.Country)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey($"PhoneCountryId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                .IsRequired(true);
        
            options.Property($"PhoneCountryId")
                .HasColumnName($"PhoneCountryId");
        
            options.Property($"PhoneCountryId")
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValue(1);
        
            options.WithOwner();
        });
```

I am configuring the actual foreign key to Country with strings here, because I dont want to put it explicitly in my class.

Desired database structure is:

| Person | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| PhoneCountryId | int (country FK) |
| PhoneNumber | string |

| Country | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| Name | string |

When I try to project/select this object from my Person table, the Country navigation is not populated.

Example:

```cs
dbContext.Persons.Select(x => x.Country.Name);
```

If I add `options.Navigation(e => e.Country).AutoInclude();` to my config, it is populated, but I need to use ".AsNoTracking()" to my query, or else I get this error:
"A tracking query is attempting to project an owned entity without a corresponding owner in its result, but owned entities cannot be tracked without their owner. Either include the owner entity in the result or make the query non-tracking using 'AsNoTracking'."

This leads me to believe that the relationship is not properly configured. It's able to determine that when I select Person.Phone.Country I get the correct country, but appearntly not that Country is owned by Person?

#### Include provider and version information

EF Core version: 7.0.2
Database provider: (e.g. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)
Target framework: (e.g. .NET 7.0)
Operating system: Linux
IDE: Rider

Comment: What is `Country`? Can you please add a [mre]? Also what is target database structure?

Comment: @GuruStron Updated the example. I dont have time to add a complete reproducible project atm.

Answer (score 0):

Error was actually due to a method call in a mapper that could not be translated, and not due to EF Core config.